# Get Security Token from WSO2 Identity Server 5.3 WS-Trust STS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have WSO2IS set up with an AD LDS user store and have a WS-Federation Passive STS prototype written in ASP.NET MVC that works and can authenticate as a user defined in AD LDS. I am now attempting to write a simple .NET console app to manually connect to the WS-Trust endpoint and authentication as this same user (or the admin user, tried both). I have secured the WS-Trust endpoint using UserNamePassword, and selected which users can authenticate.

However, when I run this prototype I get a "java.lang.NullPointerException" from WSO2IS.

What am I doing wrong or leaving out?

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException occurred   HResult=0x80131501
>   Message=java.lang.NullPointerException   Source=System.ServiceModel
>   StackTrace:    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.WSTrustChannel.ReadResponse(Message
>   response)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken
>   rst, RequestSecurityTokenResponse& rstr)    at
>   WsTrustActiveSTSClient.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Source\caci\MFOMID
>   Prototypes\STS\WSO2IS-RP\WsTrustActiveSTSClient\Program.cs:line 38

I have looked at the logs for the exception information and it seems to be thrown in org.apache.rahas.impl.SAMLTokenIssuer.createHoKAssertion.

> TID: [-1234] [] [2017-10-12 20:10:34,719] ERROR
>   {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet} -
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.rahas.impl.SAMLTokenIssuer.createHoKAssertion(SAMLTokenIssuer.java:452)
>     at
>   org.apache.rahas.impl.SAMLTokenIssuer.issue(SAMLTokenIssuer.java:202)
>     at
>   org.apache.rahas.TokenRequestDispatcher.handle(TokenRequestDispatcher.java:69)
>     at
>   org.apache.rahas.STSMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(STSMessageReceiver.java:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
>     at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:173)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:72)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:60)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Here is the source code for this simple WS-Trust STS client written using WIF 4.5 under the .NET Framework 4.5.2.

```
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Claims;
using System.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Security;

namespace WsTrustActiveSTSClient
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WS2007HttpBinding binding = new WS2007HttpBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential, false);
            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
            binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;


            EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("https://localhost:9443/services/wso2carbon-sts");

            WSTrustChannelFactory factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(binding, endpoint);
            factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "admin";
            factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "admin";

            WSTrustChannel channel = (WSTrustChannel) factory.CreateChannel();

            RequestSecurityToken rst = new RequestSecurityToken
            {
                RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
                KeyType = KeyTypes.Symmetric,
                Claims =
                {
                    new RequestClaim(ClaimTypes.Name)
                }
            };

            RequestSecurityTokenResponse rstr = null;
            SecurityToken token = channel.Issue(rst, out rstr);

            Console.WriteLine("{0}", token);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that I was requesting a Symmetric key token and it looks like I wasn't configured for that. I changed it to a Bearer token and it worked fine. I am still looking into the Symmetric key use case, though.